# Get Data From Kafka Consumer As Text

Tags: linux, kubernetes, apache-kafka

I was trying to get the data from a kafka-consumer using this command

> kubectl exec -it -n me2 `kubectl get po -n me2 | grep central | awk '{print $1}' | head -1` -- /usr/bin/kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server me-ckaf-kafka-headless:9092 --topic CdrToUsageRepRating --from-beginning

you don't need to understand the command im just asking about the kafka part

when I use this command the consumed event doesn't returned as text
I mean it is not like when you use "cat" command
this is  a problem for me
because I'm trying to automate this and I used the SSHLibrary in Robot framework
there are some functions in this library that can return the result of any completed command
and the command above is not a completed command which return a result
"it is like I'm entering the consumer "
how can I get the Consumed events as a text

Comment: what is the format the source is publishing data to kafka ? JSON or Avro or protobuf or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try passing formatter parameter along with SerDe in the command, something like this.

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9096 --topic CdrToUsageRepRating --from-beginning --formatter kafka.tools.DefaultMessageFormatter --property print.key=true --property print.value=true --property key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer --property value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongDeserializer
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the question is asking. The default string deserializer would be fine

Answer (score 0):

Kafka consumers run endlessly.

You'll need to add `--max-messages` property to be able to have that command "return" data to some other remote execution framework